# Is there a way to clean up a CSS stylesheet so that only active styling is kept

Tags: html, css, less, minify

I recently started working on a web-app project which has been built and rebuilt several times, by different developers. Every time a new version was built, the stylesheets of the old ones were kept, and were simply overridden by new stylesheets. As of today I have the following sheets :

```
style.css - 2009
styleV2.css - 2011
styleV3.css - 2012
mobile.css - 2013
tablet.less - 2014
main.less - 2014
```

I managed to build a main.less file which requires everything in the correct order, then I compile to CSS and minify it, so that I have only one, compressed file, but even like this, it is way too large (more than 250kb of compressed css!!).

I know that there are probably 50% of the rules in those stylesheets which are unused, because they are overridden one or several times by other ones. It would be too much work to doing some manual deletes, the app and the CSS are way too big for that.

I am wondering if it would be possible to keep only the "active" rules in this CSS. I have been thinking about using a web browser someway, because it knows which rules are "active", but I have no idea of how I could extract all the possible active rules to a new, cleaner and lighter stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

**grunt-uncss**

https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss

A grunt task for removing unused CSS from your projects with UnCSS. Works across multiple files and supports dynamically injected CSS via PhantomJS.

Comment: This seems to be good for a static website, but I have a web-app built with Backbone.JS where views are dynamically created. - "Along-side, specify the input HTML files you would like scanned for used selectors. In this case app/index.html and app/about.html are the two files we would like checked."

Comment: Also, the project you linked aims at removing CSS rules which are unused in some pages, while what I want to do is to remove CSS rules which are overridden by other ones and thus won't be used in any case